# Jenkins declarative pipeline Warning: JENKINS-41339 probably bogus PATH

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkinsfile

I am struggling with this issue inside my declarative pipeline. I am trying to use python's docker image as my agent and run some scripts and I am receiving warning:

```
Warning: JENKINS-41339 probably bogus PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools; perhaps you meant to use ‘PATH+EXTRA=/something/bin’
```

I do not have access to Jenkins server global variables configuration. I am using one of the Debian slaves.

I have read other issues about this problem [stackoverflow/43987005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987005/jenkins-does-not-recognize-command-sh) and [stackoverflow/44378221](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44378221/export-command-in-jenkins-pipeline/). Also discussion on [Jenkins forum](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-41339) and Jenkins official [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/).

This is code I am executing:

```
//  https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/
pipeline {
  environment {
    PATH = "/bin/sh:$PATH"
  }
  agent {
    docker {
      image "python:3.9"
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        withEnv(["PATH+EXTRA=$PATH"]) {
          sh "PATH is: $PATH"
        }
      }
      post {
        cleanup {
          cleanWs()
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        echo "'Let's build"
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
      steps {
        echo "'Let's deploy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Problem appeared after I wanted to implement docker image as agent and by changing ***environment*** section inside my pipeline still haven't fixed my problem. I was trying also these alternatives:

```
PATH = "/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
PATH = "/usr/local/bin:${env.PATH}"
```

I also went to `Configure`, section `Prepare an environment for the run` and filled up `Properties Content` input but I still didn't receive $PATH content into my job. I am still receiving global value of $PATH. I also unchecked the `Keep Jenkins Environment Variables` checkbox.

The server I am using has [Environment Injector Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/) plugin installed.

Comment: Looks like this question is already asked and answered over on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987005/jenkins-does-not-recognize-command-sh

Comment: @jayhendren I was reading that, even mentioned it at the beginning of my answer, but unfortunately nothing helped me so far.

Answer (score 1):

[This post explains that/why environment variables don't propagate to Docker agent](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/226520788-Control-environment-variables-inside-a-Docker-container).

If you need a custom container, you could define path and whatever else as layers on top of base image in a Dockerfile. Then using that image in pipeline would be what I think is usual way of doing it. You can build that image outside of Jenkins, but it's also possible to [build container from within pipeline too](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#building-containers) if you want (get Dockerfile from SCM or some other use case).

In the context of your question, I think you can still use base image, and if you know full path you'd like to set, do that at container (agent) startup with args. But `$PATH` variable won't be available at host to be resolved within container at startup. If you must dynamically set path in container, could adjust it in shells.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { 
            image 'python:3.9'
            // cannot resolve $PATH var in container (becasue HOST does not know what it is).
            args '-e PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/i/know/my/full/path/ahead/of/time'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                
                // as set by args above. Applies to all shells
                sh 'echo $PATH'
                
                // You can also adjust it within container in each shell
                sh '''
                    export PATH=/even/more/path:$PATH
                    echo $PATH
                   '''

                // But this is back to what's in args in a new shell instance
                sh 'echo $PATH'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @napovi for the answer, I ran your example with using `args` but still the same error.

Comment: Still getting 'bogus path' error? That would be odd, because you are not altering any paths in Jenkins/Pipeline in my example. Only passing absolute path to be set in the container or prepend it to your command in a `sh` block without string interpolation (single quotes). Could you post what you got now in your pipeline?

Comment: I took your example and ran it inside provided Jenkins server and I got the same `bogus PATH` error. It is very weird indeed.